# Azure Data Factory using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

Can someone tell me how we can set general features of Azure pipeline in Azure Data Factory using Python like policy variable (timeout,retry etc)?

Comment: Azure Pipeline is not a service, are you talking about Data Factory?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I am talking about data factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add `policy` parameter in your python code:

```
# Create a copy activity
act_name = 'copyBlobtoBlob'
blob_source = BlobSource()
blob_sink = BlobSink()

policy = {"timeout": "1.00:00:00",
          "concurrency": 1,
          "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
          "style": "StartOfInterval",
          "retry": 3,
          "longRetry": 0,
          "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"}

copy_activity = CopyActivity(act_name, source=blob_source, sink=blob_sink,
                             policy=policy)

# Create a pipeline with the copy activity
p_name = 'copyPipeline'
params_for_pipeline = {}
p_obj = PipelineResource(activities=[copy_activity], parameters=params_for_pipeline)
p = adf_client.pipelines.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, p_name, p_obj)
```

Test:

[image]

Hope it helps you.